# ASP.net web api with enabled cross-origin and credentials IIS deployment blocked by CORS problem

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am having a problem accessing the api that I have deployed in IIS. Even though I have this code in my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy("AllowCors", policy =>
   {
      policy.WithOrigins("https://tauri.localhost/", "http://localhost:5173")
         .AllowAnyHeader()
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowCredentials();
   });
});
```

I still got this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8001/UserAuth/Login' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:5173, http://localhost:5173', but only one is allowed.
```

I also already have this in my web.config file. Even if I put the origins that I put in program.cs in the `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://tauri.localhost/, http://localhost:5173">` I am still getting the same error

```
<configuration>
   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
      <system.webServer>
         <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
               <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
               <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />
               <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, soapaction" />
            </customHeaders>
         </httpProtocol>
         <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
         </handlers>
         <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

I don't know if I am missing something or what. This api also has an access in database sql server.

[Edited]
I have observed that whenever the controller has to access the sql server database. It throws the **has been blocked by CORS policy** error.

Comment: What you should do is to remove `customHeaders` section (legacy approach recommended by millions of old posts, but no longer valid after IIS CORS module was shipped) and switch to IIS CORS module.

Comment: Please check if there is a problem with the connection string and if the URL for accessing SQL API is correct, and here a link about iis cors module configuration you can use as a reference: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference).

Answer (score 0):

The CORS issue you're having looks like it's being caused by having duplicated CORS settings. Both the ASP.NET Core pipeline and IIS are adding CORS headers to your response, which will cause duplicated headers. This will be rejected.

Definitely only handle CORS in one place. I recommend only handling CORS in your  `program.cs`.

If you haven't already, also make sure to drop CORS into your startup.cs file.

Something like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("AllowCors");
}
```

Let me know if this solves your problem or if you get a different error

Comment: Hello @Corey, I have observed that whenever the controller has to access the sql server database. It throws the has been blocked by CORS policy error.

Comment: Hmmmm... if that's the case, it's possible that the real problem isn't CORS, but an exception occurring due to database access. I would add logging to check if this or isn't the problem. This will let you check if the actual error is trying to connect to the db